# How to upgrade from 12.10 to 14.04

Tags: 12.10, upgrade

I happen to be running Ubuntu 12.10 on my machine and I noticed that it is no longer supported since there are no quantal repositories left and I can't update or install any software any more.

I tried to run `update-manager`, but it failed to download repository information since it doesn't exist any more.

How would I proceed to upgrade this machine (without a complete new install of course)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was addressed a couple times, the relevant links are

[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

[Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Both of them suggest that it's probably a mess to upgrade from 12.10 to 14.04 since it would involve 3 upgrades, so it might be easiest to change `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` (as in the top answer in the first link) and do a fresh install when I have the time.